# Python iterator appending logic

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am trying to write an iterator class that processes and then appends data to an iterable, like

```
def processor2(data, append):
    for chunk in data:
        yield chunk
    yield append
```

however my class ended up a bit more complicated that I expected:

```
class processor(object):
    def __init__(self, data, append):
        self.finished = False
        self.data = data
        self.append = append

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.finished:
            raise StopIteration

        try:
            return next(self.data)
        except StopIteration as e:
            self.finished = True
            return self.append

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()
```

The second `yield` statement in the generator is nice and readable, but the solution using `self.finished = True` etc.
seems quite cumbersome and opaque to me. Isn't there a nicer way to create this behavior in iterator classes?

Currently, both implementations work the same:

```
data = iter(['a', 'b', 'c'])
for i in data:
    print i

data = iter(['x', 'y', 'z'])
for i in processor(data, "foo"):
    print i

data = iter(['x', 'y', 'z'])
for i in processor2(data, "foo"):
    print i
```

Comment: You need to change `return next(data)` to `return next(self.data)`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Why did this work?! :-D

Comment: @nilswerner It appeared to work because it uses the global variable named `data`

Comment: BTW, there's no need for `as e` in your `except` clause, since you don t use `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is actually the canonical implementation of what you are trying to do. There's nothing that can be improved, except minor details.

There may be equivalent approaches (such as using a sentinel, as proposed by Padraic), but the core approach remains the same: you will always need a *finished* flag.

Note that, from a certain prospective, your class is perfectly identical to the generator function: in the generator function the line number plays the role of the *finished* flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid the try/except you could use a sentinel:

```
class processor(object):
    def __init__(self, data, append):
        self.finished = False
        self.data = data
        self.append = append
        self.exhausted = object()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.finished is self.exhausted:
            raise StopIteration()
        self.finished = nxt = next(self.data, self.exhausted)
        return nxt if nxt is not self.exhausted  else self.append

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()
```

Setting self.finished equal to nxt will catch when we go one past the append:

```
In [11]: p = processor(l, 4)

In [12]: l = iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [13]: p = processor(l, 4)

In [14]: for ele in p:
           print(ele)
   ....:     
1
2
3
4
5
4

In [15]: next(p)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call
```

You could also use a for loop:

```
class processor(object):
    def __init__(self, data, append):
        self.finished = False
        self.data = data
        self.append = append

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.finished:
            raise StopIteration()
        for nxt in self.data:
            return nxt
        self.finished = True
        return self.append

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()
```

Which mimics the function and works just the same:

```
In [13]: p = processor(it, 4)

In [14]: next(p)
Out[14]: 4

In [15]: it = iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [16]: p = processor(it, 4)

In [17]: next(p)
Out[17]: 1

In [18]: next(p)
Out[18]: 2

In [19]: next(p)
Out[19]: 3

In [20]: next(p)
Out[20]: 4

In [21]: next(p)
Out[21]: 5

In [22]: next(p)
Out[22]: 4

In [23]: next(p)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
```